# How to get metric log insights for lambdas using boto3 (python sdk)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I want to get the **MemoryUsedInMB** attribute from Lambda CloudWatch logs insights. I tried the get_metrics_data function with invocations but was unsure on what the dimensions should be. Here is the command I used

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-data --cli-input-json file://test_file.json
```

Here is the test_file.json

```
{
"MetricDataQueries": [
    {
        "Id": "myRequest",
        "MetricStat": {
            "Metric": {
                "Namespace": "AWS/Lambda",
                "MetricName": "Invocations"
            },
            "Period": 3600,
            "Stat": "Sum"
        },
        "Label": "myRequestLabel",
        "ReturnData": true
    }
],
"StartTime": "2022-05-31T10:40:0000",
"EndTime": "2022-05-31T14:12:0000"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following dimensions for the lambda function

```
'Dimensions': [
                    {
                        'Name': 'FunctionName',
                        'Value': 'YourFunctionNameHere'
                    }
                ]
```